# Bépo Keyboard Layout - Can't use AltGr+Space to write _ (underscore) since blender 2.93

Tags: shortcut

I'm a Bépo user (Bépo is a specific keyboard layout for french people) and since the last blender release (2.93) I can't use my underscore anymore because the mapping used to write that is AltGr+Spacebar.

AltGr seems to be interpreted as Ctrl + Alt, so now I can't use it to rename my files, my objects, etc. The only way to do that is to copy paste "_" form outside blender.

Is there a way to retreive this ability ? It works well with blender 2.92.

Thank you guys for your awesome work and have a nice day !
Best Regards.